# C# or Powershell - deny all permissions on a file for a specific user by SID

Tags: c#, powershell, acl

I am trying to deny all permission on a file for specific user by SID.

[image]

Below powershell script is NOT working, please suggest!

if there is any solution in C#, please suggest that too. Thanks!

```
 $acl=get-acl "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apps\App1\app1.exe.config"
 $accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(""S-1-5-80-2570749625-3670579428-2043555603-1384573946-1864689131"","Read",,,"Allow")
 $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)
 Set-Acl -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Apps\App1\app1.exe.config" -AclObject $acl
```

Comment: I think you need to use the FileSystemAccessRule constructor with 3 parameters like `$accessrule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new("S-1-5-80-2570749625-3670579428-2043555603-1384573946-1864689131","Read","Allow")` to use for the `RemoveAll` method., Then create a new rule to explicitely deny all access: `$denyrule = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new("S-1-5-80-2570749625-3670579428-2043555603-1384573946-1864689131","FullControl","Deny")` and add that to the acl. Finally use the `Set-Acl` cmdlet

Comment: yes, it's working. Thanks a lot